# form.submit() --> getting 414 => Net::HTTPRequestURITooLong error

Tags: ruby, forms, uri, mechanize

I am submitting a form with four Hidden Parameters that are all fairly long.  These parameters must be passed to get the correct page.

I am doing a form.submit()

When I do that I get this error 414 => Net::HTTPRequestURITooLong

I tried removing the Hidden fields and submitting the form, but I get the wrong page returned.  I looked at the request in Charles Proxy and I do see all four Hidden variables in the request.

```
    statement_form = page.form_with(:id => 'form1')
bill =  statement_form.submit()
```

How do I get around this error?

Comment: You're probably submitting the form as GET. The params will be part of the url, making it longer.

Comment: I edited the question.  I'm doing the post above.

Comment: Hidden variables belong in the request, they're only hidden from the UA. If you're using Charles, proxy both the browser request and the mechanize one and then compare the requests in Charles.